# Getting rid of empty lines in short table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm using the `shorttoc` package for a second table of contents of my book.  Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\begin{document}

\shorttoc{Contents at a Glance}{0}

\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo}
\section{Foo1}
\section{Foo2}
\section{Foo3}
\chapter{Bar}
\section{Bar1}
\section{Bar2}
\chapter{Baz}
\section{Baz1}
\section{Baz2}
\section{Baz3}

\end{document}
```

This works fine except that the short table of contents has an empty line after each chapter which I don't want.  (The book as approximately 20 chapters which would all fit onto one page if it weren't for the blank lines.)

I do want to keep the formatting of the normal (long) ToC, though.

Comment: Have you tried the `tight` option when loading the package?

Comment: You might want to consider using something like **etoc**. Otherwise, you need to redefine the formatting of chapter contents lines for the short ToC, I think. I can't get the `tight` option to do anything no matter what I try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following cfr's idea here is a solution: the changes are local to `shorttoc`

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
{\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{\vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@}{}{}{\errmessage{paching \string\l@chapter fail}}
\patchcmd{\l@chapter}{\addvspace{1.0em \@plus\p@}}{}{}{\errmessage{paching \string\l@chapter fail}}
\shorttoc{Contents at a Glance}{0}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo}
\section{Foo1}
\section{Foo2}
\section{Foo3}
\chapter{Bar}
\section{Bar1}
\section{Bar2}
\chapter{Baz}
\section{Baz1}
\section{Baz2}
\section{Baz3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, thanks.  And I can confirm that the `tight` option has no effect.